# C# mongo paging with aggregates

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection which has multiple students and each student has multiple records like this

```
[
  {
    "studentid": "stu-1234",
    "dept": "geog",
    "Status": 1,
    "CardSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T10:50:00.5230694Z"
  },
  {
    "studentid": "stu-1234",
    "dept": "geog",
    "Status": 2,
    "CardSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T11:50:00.5230694Z"
  },
  {
    "studentid": "stu-abc",
    "dept": "geog",
    "Status": 11,
    "CardSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T09:15:00.5230694Z"
  },
  {
    "studentid": "stu-abc",
    "dept": "geog",
    "Status": 21,
    "CardSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T11:30:00.5230694Z"
  }
]
```

I have an aggregate query running and fetching multiple records like this in C# Dotnet Core 3.1. The query gets the latest record of each student based on a list of student ids and department name, in this case it will get one record for `sid=stu-abc` and one for `sid=stu-1234`.

```
string [] sids   = { array of Student ids here };
string deptName = "math";
var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$match",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {"studentid", new BsonDocument("$in",BsonArray.Create(sids))},
                {"dept",dept}
            }
        ),
            new BsonDocument("$sort",new BsonDocument("CardSwipeTimestamp", -1)),
                               
            new BsonDocument("$group",
                new BsonDocument{
                        { "_id",
                            new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "studentid","$studentid" },
                                { "dept","$dept"}
                            }
                        },
                        { "Status",new BsonDocument("$first", "$Status")},
                        { "CardSwipeTimestamp",new BsonDocument("$first", "$CardSwipeTimestamp")}
                    }
                ),
       new BsonDocument("$project",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", 0 },
                { "studentid", "$_id.studentid" },
                { "dept", "$_id.dept" },
                { "Status", "$Status" },
                { "CardSwipeTimestamp", "$CardSwipeTimestamp" }
            }
        ),
         new BsonDocument("$skip",0),
         new BsonDocument("$limit",3),
    };

collectionName.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList()
```

Assuming my collection has millions of entries with 1000s of student ids, how do I provide a way to get a paged list returned? I don't want to get all records and then use C# linq to page thru them. Can I send some page parameters to the pipeline above so I can get say 20 records at a time and move to next 20 records with an offset from the first record? Need some help in this.

EDIT

After applying skip and limit as above, I am only getting the date paged, but its not consistent.  if I pass in skip as 0 and limit=1 it gets me 3 records, but when I page to the next page, sometimes I get a record I got in the previous page.

Comment: [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group) does not order its output documents.

Comment: @Valijon I have edited my question. Check how I am applying the sort with skip and limit. Do you think the lack of ordering is the issue here which is creating an inconsistent response when applying skip and limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$sort` you need to add these two: `$skip` and `$limit`. An example is below (of course you need to parameterize it).

```cs
new BsonDocument("$skip", 0},
new BsonDocument("$limit", 20},
```

This enables the server side paging. Skip/limit require sorting otherwise your results aren't deterministic.

Now this approach works, but is not fully optimal. To be fully optimal, you need to remember the last record of the last page and start from there as a **skip** skips records sequentially from the first match in the sorted set (this means a scan, and so is linear; remembering the document allows you to do a seek, which is O(1)). This is outside of the scope of your question, but here's a [resource](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr) and [another](https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try this approach of skipping with a limit and did notice that it brings back a different set of records everytime, even if I don't change the skip and limit parameters. Here is what I tried https://mongoplayground.net/p/E26o3YILVzt

Comment: I think you might need to move skip/limit before group. Or perhaps your sort needs to include your grouping (compound sort). Either way skip/limit after a non-deterministic action like group is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work in the mongo playground, but when I put it in c# code,I get only 1 record back when using skip=0 and limit=3. That one recrd it gets back is the 3rd record.

Comment: Having to remember the last record, wont work in stateless api based environment. I can't expect the client to send the last record along with limit and skip. I don't have control over client side code.  So is this a limitation on the mongo driver side?

Comment: True, you'd have to remember the document somewhere in the API (e.g. a cache of query parameters-->last document). Not ideal, I grant you because of the statefulness.